# Testing admob adds on my device pre google play publish

Tags: android, admob

I registerd an accout on AdMob.

My app is not published yet and i want to test adds embeedment on my device.

How do i do this?

AdMob site asks to find the application on google play

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a statement like this in your code:

```
final AdRequest.Builder adReq = new AdRequest.Builder();
adReq.addTestDevice("XXXX");
```

`XXXX` is basically the representation of your device. You'll be able to get it having a look at your `LogCat` window where you'll find a line like this:

```
03-11 19:39:15.012: I/Ads(1167): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("XXXX") to get test ads on this device.
```

Comment: addTestdevice is deprecated warning is showing. Should I continue?